# Why is Haskell's default string implementation a linked list of chars?

Tags: string, performance, haskell, linked-list

The fact that Haskell's default `String` implementation is not efficient both in terms of speed and memory is well known. As far as I know the `[] lists` in general are implemented in Haskell as singly-linked lists and for most small/simple data types (e.g. `Int`) it doesn't seem like a very good idea, but for `String` it seems like total overkill. Some of the opinions on this matter include:

[Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/efficient-file-processing-regular-expressions-and-file-name-matching.html)

> On simple benchmarks like this, even programs written in interpreted languages such as Python can outperform Haskell code that uses String by an order of magnitude.

[Efficient String Implementation in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576213/efficient-string-implementation-in-haskell)

> Since a String is just [Char], that is a linked list of Char, it means Strings have poor locality of reference, and again means that Strings are fairly large in memory, at a minimum it's N * (21bits + Mbits) where N is the length of the string and M is the size of a pointer (...). Strings are much less likely to be able to be optimized to loops, etc. by the compiler.

I know that Haskell has `ByteString`s (and `Array`s) in several nice flavors and that they can do the job nicely, but I would expect the default implementation to be the most efficient one.

TL;DR: Why is Haskell's default `String` implementation a singly-linked list even though it is terribly inefficient and rarely used for real world applications (except for the really simple ones)? Are there historical reasons? Is it easier to implement?

Comment: I assume that's because `[Char]` is awfully comfortable.

Comment: I feel it's worth mentioning that `ByteString` is definitely not a text type, and `Array` isn't much better – `Text` is really the right solution.

Comment: Haskell /= GHC. Having a "turtles all the way down" string representation was a commendable design for the early days of Haskell when there were several different compilers / interpreters.

Comment: Personally, I would expect the default implementation to be one that's simple, meaningfully lazy, behaves correctly if used naively, and is "fast enough" for simple uses. `[Char]` does just fine in that regard and `ByteString` emphatically does not.

Comment: I wonder if people also complain about the existence of `StringBuilder` classes in other languages where the default string implementation is grossly inefficient for repeated concatenation...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Why is Haskell's default String implementation a singly-linked list

Because singly-linked lists support:

- induction via pattern matching
- have useful properties, such as Monad, Functor
- are properly parametrically polymorphic
- are naturally lazy

and so `String` as `[Char]` (unicode points) means a string type that fits the language goals (as of 1990), and essentially come "for free" with the list library.

In summary, historically the language designers were interested more in well-designed core data types, than the modern problems of text processing, so we have an elegant, easy to understand, easy to teach `String` type, that isn't quite a unicode text chunk, and isn't a dense, packed, strict data type.

Comment: All of the answers provided me with new valuable information, but yours is most complete (which seems to be a characteristic common to all of your answers :) ).

Comment: These are extremely nice properties. They are some of the key reasons a person would use Haskell over other languages. It's astonishing that there are alternative string implementations that give these up. Why can't the compiler implement [Char] efficiently? A somewhat generalized solution to this could make all sorts of things more efficient.

Comment: @PaulHarrison: For one thing, the others are less lazy, and the compiler won't make things stricter unless it can be certain that doing so won't change the behavior of the program. This is not, in general, an easy task.

Answer (score 12):

Efficiency is only one axis to measure an abstraction on. While lists are pretty inefficient for text-y operations, they are darn convenient in that there's a lot of list operations implemented polymorphically that have useful interpretations when specialized to `[Char]`, so you get a lot of reuse both in the library implementation and in the user's brain.

It's not clear that, were the language being designed today from scratch with our current level of experience, the same decision would be made; however, it's not always possible to make decisions perfectly before experience is available.

Comment: Quite a few text-y operations are, conceptually, operations on sequences of unicode characters that traverse the string at most once. An "efficient" text type isn't if it forces a large amount of data into memory at once rather than forcing only a few `(:)` at a time. The problems with using `[Char]` are not as catastrophic as they're sometimes described.

Answer (score 4):

At this point, it's probably historical: the optimizations that have made things like `ByteString` so efficient are *recent*, whereas `[Char]` predates them all by many years.