# Haskell version of Peter Norvig's spelling corrector is unbelievably slow

Tags: haskell, dictionary, text

As an exercise, I wrote Peter Norvig's [spelling corrector algorithm](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) in Haskell:

```
module Spl (nwords, correct)
    where

import Data.Char (toLower)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.List (maximumBy, splitAt, foldl')
import Text.Regex.TDFA (getAllTextMatches, (=~))

import qualified Data.Set as Set
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map

type NWords = Map.Map String Int


alphabet :: String
alphabet = enumFromTo 'a' 'z'

nwords :: String -> Map.Map String Int
nwords = train . words'

uniqueElems :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
uniqueElems = uniq' Set.empty
    where uniq' _ [] = []
          uniq' seen (x:xs)
            | x `Set.member` seen = uniq' seen xs
            | otherwise           = x:uniq' (x `Set.insert` seen) xs

words' :: String -> [String]
words' = getAllTextMatches . flip (=~) "[a-z]+" . map toLower

train :: [String] -> NWords
train = foldl' populate Map.empty
    where populate m feature = Map.insertWith (+) feature 1 m

edits :: String -> [String]
edits word = uniqueElems $ concat [dels, trans, repl, ins]
    where dels   = [a ++ tail b | (a,b) <- splits, nn b]
          trans  = [ a ++ (b!!1):head b:tail (tail b) | (a,b) <- splits
                   , length b > 1]
          repl   = [a ++ c:tail b | (a,b) <- splits, c <- alphabet, nn b]
          ins    = [a ++ c:b | (a,b) <- splits, c <- alphabet]
          splits = [splitAt n word | n <- [0..length word]]
          nn     = not . null

knownEdits :: NWords -> String -> [String]
knownEdits nw word = uniqueElems [ e2 | e1 <- edits word, e2 <- edits e1
                                 , Map.member e2 nw]

known :: NWords -> [String] -> [String]
known nw = uniqueElems . filter (`Map.member` nw)

correct :: NWords -> String -> String
correct nw word = fst $ maximumBy (comparing snd) candidates
    where candidates = [(w, Map.findWithDefault 0 w nw) | w <- result]
          result     = head $ filter (not . null) start
          start      = [ known nw [word], known nw $ edits word
                       , knownEdits nw word , [word]]
```

**Usage**
This is how I would use it:

```
ghci> t <- readFile "big.txt"
ghci> let nw = nwords t
ghci> correct nw "speling"
"spelling"
```

The `big.txt` file is available on Peter Norvig's site (direct link, 6.2MB):
http://norvig.com/big.txt

**Problems**

- Building the words map takes *ages*. The `train` function is much slower, than `words'`, so it's the bottleneck.
- Memory usage is insane. After playing for a while I got it to almost 1 GB.

So, where did I get it wrong? Do I have a memory leak somewhere?

Comment: You are using the wrong data structure. Have you considered using a [**Trie**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) from [**`Data.Trie`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-trie-0.2.3/docs/Data-Trie.html), not a **Tree**?

Comment: How did you find out that `train` is the bottleneck? There is no way to discover that using just the usage example in the question, so I guess you must have tested/benchmarked it in some other way.

Comment: What was your input to get to 1 GB?

Comment: TDFA is really slow. It would be nice if there was a fast, native `Text` version of TDFA but there currently is not (the tdfa-text just converts to `String` before processing). You should consider using a more optimized regex package, even though most of them have some undesirable behavior and are backed by a C library.

Comment: @duplode I just timed various statements. Nothing too deep, I know, but after a while I realized that I must have gotten wrong all the implementation, because there's an abyss between this version and the Python one. I'll rewrite it using tries and report back.

Comment: @user5402 I loaded words from Norvig's `big.txt` file and played with the functions in the interpreter.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson That's unfortunate. I chose it after reading [this page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Regular_expressions) on Haskell's wiki. In the table `regex-tdfa` is reported as fast.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Given that the regex here is just `[a-z]+`, I wonder if a regex library is necessary at all. Perhaps `filter (not null && all isLetter) . words` (or an equivalent thereof for `Text`, if/when the OP switches to that) would be enough?

Comment: compile the regex, and don't try to look at performance of things from GHCi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My main suggestions are:

- use an efficient string type (i.e. Text / ByteString or their lazy variants)
- use a better hash map implementation - something like `Data.HashMap.Strict`
- write a custom word parser instead of using regexs

The following code can load all of `big.txt` into a `Data.Hashmap.Strict` in about 2 secs. Memory usage is about 25 MB (on a 64-bit system):

```
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as H
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import Data.List

isAlpha ch = ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z') || ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z')

wrds :: T.Text -> [ T.Text ]
wrds bs =
  let
      (_, r1) = T.span (not . isAlpha) bs
      (w, r2) = T.span isAlpha r1
  in if T.null w then [] else T.toLower w : wrds r2

readDict = do
  allwords <- fmap wrds $ T.readFile "big.txt"
  let h = foldl' add H.empty all words
      add h w = let c = H.lookupDefault (0 :: Int)  w h
                in  H.insert w (c+1) h
      member = \k -> H.member k h
      frequency = \k -> H.lookupDefault 0 k h
  return (member, frequency)
```

It might be more efficient to use lazy Text - something to investigate.

Here's the rest of my implementation - pretty much follows Norvig but I've made some other choices which you might find interesting:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module SpellText
where

import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Monoid
import Data.List.Ordered (nubSort)
import Data.Ord
import Data.List
import Control.Monad

type Dict = ( Text -> Bool, Text -> Int )

singles :: [ Text ]
singles = map T.singleton ['a'..'z']

edits :: Text -> [ Text ]
edits w = deletes <> nubSort (transposes <> replaces) <> inserts
  where
    splits     = zip (T.inits w) (T.tails w)
    deletes    = [ a <> (T.drop 1 b) | (a,b) <- splits, T.length b > 0 ]
    transposes = [ a <> c <> (T.drop 2 b) | (a,b) <- splits, T.length b > 1,
                   let c = T.pack [ T.index b 1, T.index b 0 ] ]
    replaces   = [ a <> c <> (T.drop 1 b) | (a,b) <- splits, T.length b > 1,
                    c <- singles ]
    inserts    = [ a <> c <> b | (a,b) <- splits, c <- singles ]

orElse :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
orElse [] bs = bs
orElse as _  = as

-- | Correct a word. 'isMember' and 'frequency' are functions to
--   determine if a word is in the dictionary and to lookup its
--   frequency, respectively.
correct :: Dict -> Text -> Text 
correct (isMember,frequency) w0 = 
  let ed0 = [ w0 ]
      ed1 = edits w0
      ed2 = [ e2 | e1 <- ed1, e2 <- edits e1 ]

      kn0 = filter isMember ed0
      kn1 = filter isMember ed1
      kn2 = filter isMember ed2

      candidates = kn0 `orElse` (kn1 `orElse` (kn2 `orElse` [w0]))
  in maximumBy (comparing frequency) candidates
```

Usage goes like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import ... -- import the above code

main = do
  dictfns <- readDict
  print $ correct dictfns "howwa"
```

My measured correction time is comparable to the Python version - perhaps 10% faster.

Comment: Could `wrds` be improved by using `let (w, r2) = T.span isAlpha . T.dropWhile (not . isAlpha)`, because at least that has a chance of fusing? I'd also write `wrds` as an unfold instead of direct recursion.

Comment: That would be something to investigate. The code is available [here](https://goo.gl/uymtjV) if you want to play around with it. The main point is that you can do reasonably well with a direct approach if you employ the right data structures. There are trade-offs using lazy text vs text in terms of speed and memory used and there are alternate hash map implementations which can be used.

Comment: @Cactus - seems to shave about .1 secs off of the loading time - see Test4b in the repo.

Comment: Apparently `String`s are awful in term of performance, compared to `Text`. I wonder why they're the default then. Your version is much better than mine. I could probably try Tries also. That way it would consume less memory, wouldn't it? In any case, as of now memory consuption dropped considerably and it's not an issue. Probably regexes and Strings were the culprit.

Comment: It's an historical accident. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13866019/866915 for more details.

Comment: @user5402: So... 5% improvement? I think it's worth changing it in your original answer.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, it's not that slow as it seems. The most time is consumed in `nwords`. The other function, `correct`, is actually quite fast. On my machine, `nwords` takes about 6.5s, and `correct` takes less then 0.1s, which matches the processing speed of 10 words per seconds, which was Peter Norvigs target.

I could make a 20% performance improvement by `force`ing the input and output  of the `train` function.

I compiled the program with `ghc -o Spl -O2 Spl.hs`.

```
module Main (nwords, correct, main)
    where

import Data.Char (toLower)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.List (maximumBy, splitAt, foldl')
import Text.Regex.TDFA (getAllTextMatches, (=~))

import Control.DeepSeq (deepseq, force)
import Control.Exception (evaluate)
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX

import qualified Data.Set as Set
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map

type NWords = Map.Map String Int


alphabet :: String
alphabet = enumFromTo 'a' 'z'

nwords :: String -> Map.Map String Int
nwords = train . words'

uniqueElems :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
uniqueElems = uniq' Set.empty
    where uniq' _ [] = []
          uniq' seen (x:xs)
            | x `Set.member` seen = uniq' seen xs
            | otherwise           = x:uniq' (x `Set.insert` seen) xs

words' :: String -> [String]
words' = getAllTextMatches . flip (=~) "[a-z]+" . map toLower

-- have a 20% performance improvement by using 'force' on input and output
train :: [String] -> NWords
train = force . foldl' populate Map.empty . force
    where populate m feature = Map.insertWith (+) feature 1 m

edits :: String -> [String]
edits word = uniqueElems $ concat [dels, trans, repl, ins]
    where dels   = [a ++ tail b | (a,b) <- splits, nn b]
          trans  = [ a ++ (b!!1):head b:tail (tail b) | (a,b) <- splits
                   , length b > 1]
          repl   = [a ++ c:tail b | (a,b) <- splits, c <- alphabet, nn b]
          ins    = [a ++ c:b | (a,b) <- splits, c <- alphabet]
          splits = [splitAt n word | n <- [0..length word]]
          nn     = not . null

knownEdits :: NWords -> String -> [String]
knownEdits nw word = uniqueElems [ e2 | e1 <- edits word, e2 <- edits e1
                                 , Map.member e2 nw]

known :: NWords -> [String] -> [String]
known nw = uniqueElems . filter (`Map.member` nw)

correct :: NWords -> String -> String
correct nw word = fst $ maximumBy (comparing snd) candidates
    where candidates = [(w, Map.findWithDefault 0 w nw) | w <- result]
          result     = head $ filter (not . null) start
          start      = [ known nw [word], known nw $ edits word
                       , knownEdits nw word , [word]]

main = do
    time0 <- getPOSIXTime
    t <- readFile "big.txt"
    time1 <- getPOSIXTime
    putStrLn $ ":: readFile: "++(show $ time1-time0)

    let nw = nwords t
    evaluate $ force nw
    time2 <- getPOSIXTime
    putStrLn $ ":: nwords: " ++ (show $ time2-time1)

    putStrLn $ correct nw "speling"
    putStrLn $ correct nw "miracl"
    putStrLn $ correct nw "helllo"
    putStrLn $ correct nw "rabit"
    putStrLn $ correct nw "kitteen"
    putStrLn $ correct nw "breaks"
    putStrLn $ correct nw "sometheeng"
    putStrLn $ correct nw "clessical"
    putStrLn $ correct nw "theater"
    putStrLn $ correct nw "dishis"
    time3 <- getPOSIXTime
    putStrLn $ ":: correcting: " ++ (show $ time3-time2)

    let a = time1-time0
    let b = time2-time1
    let c = time3-time2
    let total = time3 - time0
    putStrLn $ ":: total:  "++(show $ time3-time0)
```

And this is my output:

```
:: readFile: 0.000202s
:: nwords: 6.063617s
spelling
miracle
hello
habit
kitten
breaks
something
classical
theater
dishes
:: correcting: 0.749441s
:: total:  6.81326s
```

Furthermore, the `nwords` function becomes twice as fast if you don't use regexes:

```
words' :: String -> [String]
words' str = map (map toLower) $ words str
    where words str = if (null a)
                        then (if null b then [] else words f)
                        else a:(words d)
                            where (a,b) = span  isAlpha str
                                  (c,d) = break isAlpha b
                                  (e,f) = break isAlpha str
```

Interestingly, if you try to correct unknown words, it takes much longer to correct them.

(I'm a haskell beginner, and I'm trying to learn the language by answering stackoverflow questions, and by writing some toy programs.)

---

about the memory consumption:

This version just takes 21MB at most, at my system. It seems that there is a space leak if you either use regexes, or if you use `force` in `train`. If you omit both, it behaves fine. I think it has to do with the fact that the self-written `words'` function is more lazy than the regex-`words'` function.

```
module Main (nwords, correct, main)
    where

import Data.Char (toLower)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.List (maximumBy, splitAt, foldl')

import Control.DeepSeq (force)
import Control.Exception (evaluate)
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX
import Data.Char (isAlpha)

import qualified Data.Set as Set
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map

type NWords = Map.Map String Int


alphabet :: String
alphabet = enumFromTo 'a' 'z'

nwords :: String -> Map.Map String Int
nwords = train . words'

uniqueElems :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
uniqueElems = uniq' Set.empty
    where uniq' _ [] = []
          uniq' seen (x:xs)
            | x `Set.member` seen = uniq' seen xs
            | otherwise           = x:uniq' (x `Set.insert` seen) xs

words' :: String -> [String]
words' str = map (map toLower) $ words str
    where words str = if (null a)
                        then (if null b then [] else words f)
                        else a:(words d)
                            where (a,b) = span isAlpha str
                                  (c,d) = break isAlpha b
                                  (e,f) = break isAlpha str

train :: [String] -> NWords
train = foldl' populate Map.empty
    where populate m feature = Map.insertWith (+) feature 1 m

edits :: String -> [String]
edits word = uniqueElems $ concat [dels, trans, repl, ins]
    where dels   = [a ++ tail b | (a,b) <- splits, nn b]
          trans  = [ a ++ (b!!1):head b:tail (tail b) | (a,b) <- splits
                   , length b > 1]
          repl   = [a ++ c:tail b | (a,b) <- splits, c <- alphabet, nn b]
          ins    = [a ++ c:b | (a,b) <- splits, c <- alphabet]
          splits = [splitAt n word | n <- [0..length word]]
          nn     = not . null

knownEdits :: NWords -> String -> [String]
knownEdits nw word = uniqueElems [ e2 | e1 <- edits word, e2 <- edits e1
                                 , Map.member e2 nw]

known :: NWords -> [String] -> [String]
known nw = uniqueElems . filter (`Map.member` nw)

correct :: NWords -> String -> String
correct nw word = fst $ maximumBy (comparing snd) candidates
    where candidates = [(w, Map.findWithDefault 0 w nw) | w <- result]
          result     = head $ filter (not . null) start
          start      = [ known nw [word], known nw $ edits word
                       , knownEdits nw word , [word]]

main = do
    time0 <- getPOSIXTime
    t <- readFile "big.txt"
    time1 <- getPOSIXTime
    putStrLn $ ":: readFile: "++(show $ time1-time0)

    let nw = nwords t
    evaluate $ force nw
    time2 <- getPOSIXTime
    putStrLn $ ":: nwords: " ++ (show $ time2-time1)

    putStrLn $ correct nw "speling"
    putStrLn $ correct nw "miracl"
    putStrLn $ correct nw "helllo"
    putStrLn $ correct nw "rabit"
    putStrLn $ correct nw "kitteen"
    putStrLn $ correct nw "breaks"
    putStrLn $ correct nw "sometheeng"
    putStrLn $ correct nw "clessical"
    putStrLn $ correct nw "theater"
    putStrLn $ correct nw "dishis"
    time3 <- getPOSIXTime
    putStrLn $ ":: correcting: " ++ (show $ time3-time2)

    let a = time1-time0
    let b = time2-time1
    let c = time3-time2
    let total = time3 - time0
    putStrLn $ ":: total:  "++(show $ time3-time0)
```

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson : since I can read minds, I know that you are referring to lazy IO :-p ... so, the readFile would take 0.7 seconds if it were not lazy. I just measured it with evaluate and force. Still no big deal, compared to the other tasks.

Comment: Thank you Michael! Indeed, regex search was quite slow and memory hogging. Replacing it with a pure Haskell function improves the performance quite a bit.