# String concatenation in Haskell and unwanted quotes

Tags: haskell

I would like to concatenate a bunch of strings using `shows` because of efficiency (there might be a lot of them). However, when I do this I get unwanted `"` characters:

```
Prelude> "a" ++ "b" ++ "c"
"abc" -- ordinary concatenation - expected result
Prelude> (shows "a" . shows "b" . shows "c") ""
"\"a\"\"b\"\"c\"" -- actual result
```

Could someone please explain why does this happen and what should I do to achieve the `++` behaviour using the `shows` function?

When I looked at the types of those above (just out of curiosity), I got the following:

```
Prelude> :t ("a" ++ "b" ++ "c")
("a" ++ "b" ++ "c") :: [Char]
Prelude> :t ((shows "a" . shows "b" . shows "c") "")
((shows "a" . shows "b" . shows "c") "") :: String
```

Does the `[Char]` in one case and `String` in the other case have to do anything with the behaviour of `++` and `shows`, even if `String` is just an alias for `[Char]`?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576213/efficient-string-implementation-in-haskell).

Comment: The `[Char]` versus `String` is just an artifact of how type checking operates; it's probably because `(++)` operates on a general type `[a]` while `shows` is specific to `String`. There is no difference at all between `[Char]` and `String`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function `shows`, like `show`, converts any type of data (of class `Show`) to a Haskell expression notation. For strings, this involves adding quotes and escaping special characters inside the string.

If you want to concatenate *difference strings*, use `(++)` for strings instead of `shows`. E.g.

```
shows 3 . (++) " , " . shows 4
```

Answer (score 9):

Note that `show "a"` is `"\"a\""`.  The point of `show` is to print something that can be interpreted by Haskell as a literal value with `Read`.  So "showing" a string means including the quote characters.  Instead you can use the `showChar` to build up a list like this:

```
> (showChar 'a' . showChar 'b' . showChar 'c') ""
"abc"
> length it  -- `it` refers to the result of the last computation in GHCi
3
```

Answer (score 7):

`"a"` is to `show "a"` as `("a" ++)` is to `shows "a"`. So:

```
> "a" ++ "b" ++ "c"
"abc"
> show "a" ++ show "b" ++ show "c"
"\"a\"\"b\"\"c\""
> (("a" ++) . ("b" ++) . ("c" ++)) ""
"abc"
> (shows "a" . shows "b" . shows "c") ""
"\"a\"\"b\"\"c\""
```

Answer (score 0):

From practical point of view, if you are really worried about efficiency you might want to use blaze-builder. The code would be something like:

```
unpack $ toLazyByteString (fromString "a" <> fromString "b" <> fromString "c")
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `Data.Text.append` for efficient chunking of strings.